# Google Chrome limits borders of a page with blue dotted lines

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, border

Now I'm working on my pet project of a blog using Django. When I run the server in Google Chrome, it shows these blue dotted lines on a page, thus displacing all elements. At the same time, when I access the same site on Microsoft Edge, everything looks okay. What is the problem with this page in Chrome?

The page looks like this in Chrome:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgwM6.png)

And like this in Edge:
[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I24qi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem here: [https://community.pega.com/support/support-articles/blue-border-appears-all-ui-elements-chrome#:~:text=This%20is%20an%20accessibility%20feature,it%20is%20a%20dotted%20line](https://community.pega.com/support/support-articles/blue-border-appears-all-ui-elements-chrome#:%7E:text=This%20is%20an%20accessibility%20feature,it%20is%20a%20dotted%20line).
It required adding :focus { outline:none; } to the css file. Hope it may be useful to someone)

Comment: Although I think it is weird that it happens in the first place, removing outline from :focus is not always best practice. Outlining focused element by default contributes a lot to accessibility of ur website. Refer to: https://www.w3.org/WAI/test-evaluate/preliminary/#interaction